# Cramer's Rule & determinant & system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, determinant

We have the determinant below using Cramer's rule, it seems very simple but I still don't know why.

Let $g(x, y)=\sum_{k=0}^m\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ k\end{array}\right) b_k x^k y^{m-k}$ be a form of degree $m$. Then the coefficients $b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_m$ of $g(x, y)$ satisfy the following system of linear equations:

$(-1)^m a_0 b_m+(-1)^{m-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ 1\end{array}\right) a_1 b_{m-1}+(-1)^{m-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ 2\end{array}\right) a_2 b_{m-2}+\cdots+a_m b_0=0$
$(-1)^m a_1 b_m+(-1)^{m-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ 1\end{array}\right) a_2 b_{m-1}+(-1)^{m-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ 2\end{array}\right) a_3 b_{m-2}+\cdots+a_{m+1} b_0=0$

$\vdots$

$(-1)^m a_{m-1} b_m+(-1)^{m-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ 1\end{array}\right) a_m b_{m-1}+\cdots \quad+a_{2 m-1} b_0=0$.

Solving this for $b_0, \ldots, b_m$ using Cramer's rule and regrouping the terms into a determinant, we obtain
$$
g(x, y)=(-1)^m\left|\begin{array}{lllll}
a_0 & -\left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
1
\end{array}\right) a_1 & \left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
2
\end{array}\right) a_2 & \cdots & (-1)^m a_{m} \\
a_1 & -\left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
1
\end{array}\right) a_2 & \left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
2
\end{array}\right) a_3 & & (-1)^m a_{m+1} \\
a_2 & -\left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
1
\end{array}\right) a_3 & \left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
2
\end{array}\right) a_4 & & (-1)^m a_{m+2} \\
\vdots & & & \\
a_{m-1} & -\left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
1
\end{array}\right) a_m & \cdots & \\
x^m & \left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
1
\end{array}\right) x^{m-1} y & \left(\begin{array}{c}
m \\
2
\end{array}\right) x^{m-2} y^2 & \cdots & y^m
\end{array}\right|
$$

I have tried to add one more equation $g(x, y)=\sum_{k=0}^m\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ k\end{array}\right) b_k x^k y^{m-k}$  to this system of linear equations to make use of Cramer's rule, and the determinant below is one column less.

I also have asked my friends for help, but there is still no answer. I'll appreciate it very much if you could explain this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I have revised, thanks for the reminder.